# Convert 'pipe-separetd' string to multidimensional array

Tags: php, mariadb

I am working on a listing of elements, which can be related to each other in multiple ways.
Elements are stored in MariaDB in table 'elements'.
Element-relations are stored in table 'element-relations'

**Database-Example:**
*Table 'elements'*

```
[1] Earth
[2] Mars
[3] Desert
[4] Sand
[5] Grain
[6] Sea
[7] Island
```

*Table 'element-relations'*

```
rel 01: [1]<=>[3] (Earth<=>Desert)
rel 02: [1]<=>[4] (Earth<=>Sea)
rel 03: [2]<=>[3] (Mars<=>Desert)
rel 04: [3]<=>[4] (Desert<=>Sand)
rel 05: [4]<=>[5] (Sand<=>Grain)
rel 06: [6]<=>[7] (Sea<=>Island)
```

**Treeview-Example**
In this example 'Desert' is related as well to 'Earth' as to 'Mars'.
In a treeview they are recursively listed like this

```
+- Earth    [1]
+-- Desert  [3]
+--- Sand   [4]
+---- Grain [5]
+-- Sea     [6]
+--- Island [7]
+- Mars     [2]
+-- Desert  [3]
+--- Sand   [4]
+---- Grain [5]
```

The elements in the treeview are exapandable/collapsable, so I can hide subtrees.

```
+- Earth    [1] (expanded)
+-- Desert  [3] (linked to Earth; expanded)
+--- Sand   [4] (linked to Desert; expanded)
+---- Grain [5] (linked to Sand; expanded but last element in treeview)
o-- Sea     [6] (linked to Earth; collapsed)
+- Mars     [2] (expanded)
+-- Desert  [3] (linked to Mars, expanded)
o--- Sand   [4] (linked to Desert; collapsed)
```

Because sub-elements of 'Desert' (Sand, Grain) are inherited there is only one relation entry for 'Sand' and 'Grain' in table 'element-relations' althoug they are appearing below 'Earth' AND 'Mars'.
To handle the expand-state of the sub-elements independendly, I tried to use fingerprints created from the breadcrumps of an element.

```
+- Earth    [1] => fp|1
+-- Desert  [3] => fp|1|3
+--- Sand   [4] => fp|1|3|4
+---- Grain [5] => fp|1|3|4|5
o-- Sea     [6] => fp|1|6
+- Mars     [2] => fp|2
+-- Desert  [3] => fp|2|3
o--- Sand   [4] => fp|2|3|4
```

Last I created a table 'elements_state' where I store the fingerprint and the collapse/expand-state
*Table 'elements-state'*

```
[0] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|1
    'show_subtree' => 1
[1] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|1|3'
    'show_subtree' => 1
[2] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|1|3|4'
    'show_subtree' => 1 //(Element 'Sand' is expanded)
[3] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|1|3|4|5'
    'show_subtree' => 1
[4] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|1|6'
    'show_subtree' => 0
[5] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|2'
    'show_subtree' => 1
[6] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|2|3'
    'show_subtree' => 1
[7] 'fingerprint'  => 'fp|2|3|4'
    'show_subtree' => 0 //(Element 'Sand' is collapsed)
```

**The question/my problem:** How to get the state of an element with fingerprint?
My thoughts:

1. SELECT every single state by "WHERE fingerprint='fp|....'" would be overhead, having hundreds or thousands of elements.
2. SELECT * and past it into an array would be quite faster.

So how to deal with an array?
2.1) Put everything into a 2-dimensional array and then search for the string 'fp|....' within the array

```
$elementState[0]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|1'
$elementState[0]['show_subtree'] => 1
$elementState[1]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|1|3'
$elementState[1]['show_subtree'] => 1
$elementState[2]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|1|3|4'
$elementState[2]['show_subtree'] => 1  //(Element 'Sand' is expanded)
$elementState[3]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|1|3|4|5'
$elementState[3]['show_subtree'] => 1
$elementState[4]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|1|6'
$elementState[4]['show_subtree'] => 0
$elementState[5]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|2'
$elementState[5]['show_subtree'] => 1
$elementState[6]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|2|3'
$elementState[6]['show_subtree'] => 1
$elementState[7]['fingerprint']  => 'fp|2|3|4'
$elementState[7]['show_subtree'] => 0  //(Element 'Sand' is collapsed)
```

**Question 1: What would be the fastest way (without looping) to get the values?**

2.2) Split the 'fingerprint' and put everything into a n-dimensional array.

```
$elementState[1]['show_subtree']          => 1
$elementState[1][3]['show_subtree']       => 1
$elementState[1][3][4]['show_subtree']    => 1 //(Element 'Sand' is expanded)
$elementState[1][3][4][5]['show_subtree'] => 1
$elementState[1][6]['show_subtree']       => 0
$elementState[2]['show_subtree']          => 1
$elementState[2][3]['show_subtree']       => 1
$elementState[2][3][4]['show_subtree']    => 0 //(Element 'Sand' is collapsed)
```

**Question 2.1: How to convert the fingerprint-strings from table 'elements-states' into the n-dimensional array?**
**Question 2.2: How to improve access of the array-elements from a given fingerprint-string of a listed element?**
Then access it by array-element-key (due to my inability of useing something like strval() use a loop...)

```
$fingerprintOfCurrentElement = 'fp|1|3|4'; //will be concatenated by the Listing-Loop
$fingerprintArrayExplode = explode('|', $fingerprintOfCurrentElement); //split the string
array_shift($fingerprintArrayExplode); //get rid of first element ('fp')

unset($currentFingerprintState); //clear state of last element
foreach($fingerprintArrayExplode as $currentFingerprintKey) {  //loop throug dimensions of array '$elementState'
  if (!(isset($currentFingerprintState))) {  //if $currentFingerprintState is unset, fill it with full array of dimension/key '$currentFingerprintKey'
    $currentFingerprintState = $elementState[$currentFingerprintKey];
  } else {  //if $currentFingerprintState is set, fill it with values of next dimension/key
    $currentFingerprintState = $currentFingerprintState[$currentFingerprintKey];
  }
}
$elementExpandState = $currentFingerprintStates['show_subtree'];
```

Not working (with different ways to concatenate the strval-string):

```
$fingerprintOfCurrentElement = 'fp|1|3|4'; //will be concatenated by the Listing-Loop
$fingerprintArrayExplode = explode('|', $fingerprintOfCurrentElement); //split the string
array_shift($fingerprintArrayExplode); //get rid of first element ('fp')
$elementExpandState = strval('elementState[' . implode('][', $fingerprintArrayExplode) . '][\'show_subtree\']');
```

I think I am missing something or stand in my own way.

Comment: Do you need to have multiple sets of the expanded states, for instance to track states for multiple users, or should there be one single state?

Comment: Also, do you need to make use of the state data outside the context where the tree is displayed, or is this simply to re-render a tree view in the same state it was the last time the user interacted with the tree?

Comment: There will be/are multiple projects with their own sets of state - but these projects have their own tables and table-prefixes so the states of each project will have their own table.

Comment: Each project will be edited by only one user. For the moment 1 set of states per project per user. These states have to be available only in the tree-view. I disabled the multi-user-function (which at the moment is more likely an experiment) and put what I already have to a separated webpage (sorry, the list-elements are in German): [link](https://web.gate.apamo.eu/tive.narra/demo/plotmanager/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, your concept is sound, however I suggest that you simplify your approach a bit. I think you may be overthinking the "fingerprint" aspect, it should just be a hash that identifies a node in the tree, and you only really need to store open states. I think that your your idea of pulling all of the states from the database at once is correct, there is no need to query for each node. If you only store the open states, this should be very efficient.

The strategy should be to calculate the fingerprint (I'm going to call it a hash) for each node as you are building the tree structure, as you are now. You can then check to see if that hash is in your stored set corresponding to the open nodes. If it is present, set an "open" flag on the node object. If no hash is present, we know that the node should be closed. Also store the hash on the node object, and use that to pass back to your state storage mechanism when the node is opened or closed. The storage mechanism for the open states should not know about the logic or backing data used to generate the hashes - it should just store the strings. All of the logic should be in your tree creation routine.

I coded up an example ([runnable gist](https://gist.github.com/55dea6741df119017c989d288a58c4d5)), here are the most relevant pieces. This is a fairly generic tree, the important parts are the way that the "branch vectors" are built and used to generate the hashes in order to check the set of open state hashes.

```php
class TreeNode implements JsonSerializable
{
    public Element   $element;
    public bool      $isOpen   = false;
    public string    $hash;
    public ?TreeNode $parent   = null;
    public array     $children = [];

    public function __construct(Element $element, string $hash)
    {
        $this->element = $element;
        $this->hash    = $hash;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'element' => $this->element,
            'parent' => $this->parent,
            'open' => $this->isOpen,
            'hash' => $this->hash,
            'children' => $this->children
        ];
    }
}

class TreeView implements JsonSerializable
{
    private ElementService $elementService;

    // This holds the structure of TreeNodes
    private $treeStruct = [];
    private $openHashes;

    public function __construct(ElementService $elementService)
    {
        $this->elementService = $elementService;

        /*
         * Fetch all of the open state hashes for reference during tree creation
         */
        $openElementRecords = $elementService->openStatesRepository->fetchAllRecords();
        $this->openHashes = array_column($openElementRecords, 'hash');

        /*
         * Fetch all relations and use the parent and child IDs to determine
         * which elements are root nodes in the tree structure
         */
        $relations = $elementService->relationRepository->fetchAllRecords();

        $parentIds = array_column($relations, 'parent_id');
        $childIds  = array_column($relations, 'child_id');

        $rootIds = array_unique(array_diff($parentIds, $childIds));

        /*
         * For each root element, create a TreeNode, add the node to our tree struct,
         */
        foreach ($rootIds as $currId)
        {
            // Fetch the element
            $currRootElement = $elementService->elementRepository->findById($currId);

            /*
             * Create an array to hold the branch vector - this is the array of "breadcrumbs"
             * that will be used to calculate the hash for each node in the branch
             */
            $branchVector = [];

            // Create a TreeNode for our element
            $currRootNode       = $this->buildTreeNode($currRootElement, $branchVector);

            // Add the node to our struct
            $this->treeStruct[] = $currRootNode;

            // Build the branch for this root node
            $this->buildBranch($currRootNode, $branchVector);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursive function to traverse down branches of the element tree, building a corresponding
     * structure of TreeNodes
     * @param TreeNode $parentNode
     * @param array $branchVector array of element IDs indicating position in the tree
     */
    private function buildBranch(TreeNode &$parentNode, $branchVector = [])
    {
        // Get the children of the parent node's element
        $childElements = $this->elementService->getChildrenForElement($parentNode->element);

        // Loop through the children
        foreach ($childElements as $currChildElement)
        {
            // We need to create a copy of the branch vector for this new sub-branch
            $subBranchVector = $branchVector;

            // Create a new TreeNode from the current child element and branch vector
            $newNode = $this->buildTreeNode($currChildElement, $subBranchVector);

            // Set parent on the child
            $newNode->parentNode = $parentNode;

            // Set child on the parent
            $parentNode->children[] = $newNode;

            // Recurse
            $this->buildBranch($newNode, $subBranchVector);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new TreeNode for an Element
     * Updates the provided branch vector with the element's ID
     * Sets the open state appropriately based upon the branch vector
     * @param Element $element
     * @param array $branchVector
     * @return TreeNode
     */
    private function buildTreeNode(Element $element, array &$branchVector)
    {
        // Append this element's ID to the branch vector
        $branchVector[] = $element->getId();

        // Generate a has from the branch vector
        $nodeHash = self::generateHashFromBranchVector($branchVector);

        // Instantiate a new TreeNode and set the open state
        $node         = new TreeNode($element, $nodeHash);

        // If we have a matching hash in the database, set the flag true
        $node->isOpen = (in_array($nodeHash, $this->openHashes));

        return $node;
    }

    public static function generateHashFromBranchVector(array $branchVector): string
    {
        /*
         * Some algorithm for generating a hash based upon the branch vector, doesn't
         * really matter what it is. We could just concatenate the IDs with a delimiter.
         *
         * I prefer something more opaque to the user. We need something that generates
         * short strings for low overhead, and has little to no chance of collisions.
         * Let's use Base 64 encoding - bonus points for reversibility in case we need
         * it for debugging.
         */
        $raw = implode('|', $branchVector);
        return base64_encode($raw);
    }

    // Return the tree structure
    public function getStruct()
    {
        return $this->treeStruct;
    }

    // Implement JsonSerializable so we can just pass the whole TreeView instance to json_encode
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->getStruct();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, here is the difference between a server administrator who codes a bit as a hobby and a professional developer :) But I understand your suggestions and improvements. Some of them I can implement quite easy. Some of them will last me some time. Meanwhile I thought about storing the branch vector as a json-string. But just storing open-states in a one-dimensional array... yes, of course. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks alot for your answer. I prefer using arrays instead of objects but I transfered your advices. I also overthought and simplified the structure of my script. As adviced I solved my problem by storing branchVectors [bV] only of opened nodes in flat 'state'-arrays (1 for each db-stored state). I now build up an array containing all "nodes" of my treeview with unique [bV] (will be replaced later by hashes). Each node keeps it's own state(s) by searching its [bV] in the state-arrays. Thanks to the node-assigned [bV] I can now address the html/DOM objects in a very efficient way.